# Adding subpath with haproxy

Tags: reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have a website that currently has multiple subpath according to need. For example -

```
backend.com:3000/index
backend.com:3000/contact-us
backend.com:3000/help
```

I wanted to configure haproxy in such a way that I can add a parent-path before the above -

```
frontend.com:80/my-app/index
frontend.com:80/my-app/contact-us
frontend.com:80/my-app/help
```